# Python subproccess module: send string to two chained subprocesses

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to send a string to the first processes's stdin and chain it's stdout to the second processe's stdin

First program is `paps`, a text to postscript converter which accepts as input a textfile or string and ouputs a postscript file to stdout

Second Program is `lpr`, the line printer command. The process goes like this:

1. Write a string to First Program's stdin
2. Pipe the output of the first program to the stdin of the second.
3. The output of the second program is handled by itself like this in unix:

`echo "The String" | paps | lpr`

Here is what I've tried from the python docs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

paps=Popen(["/usr/local/bin/paps"],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
lpr=Popen(["/usr/bin/lpr"],stdin=paps.stdout)
paps.communicate("ABCD")
paps.stdout.close()
lpr.communicate()[0]
```

This is from the documentation:

```
#p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
#p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
#p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
#output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

In my case, the original output originates within my program and is sent to the stdin of the first process.

Comment: ...and?  Don't leave me hanging!

Comment: So, what it the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
lpr=Popen(["/usr/bin/lpr"],stdin=paps.stdout)
```

How about `stdout=PIPE`?